# JavaScript's inline If/Else with string concatenation returns unexpected value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

I am using this JavaScript code to add an item into an array of objects containing search criteria.

My goal is to use "T00:00:00" if the search criterion is the beginning of the date range, and "T23:59:59" if it is the end of the date range.

```
//key = "Created", 
//value = "2016-11-23", 
//to_from = "from"
collectedValues.push({
                key: key,
                value: (value + 
                    (to_from === "to") ?
                        "T23:59:59" :   // when searching by date range,
                        "T00:00:00"),   // "from" must be 00:00 and 
                                        // "to" must be 23:59
                isPartialMatch: false,
                toFrom: to_from
            });
```

The resulting array of objects has the wrong value for the item's "value" property. It is supposed to be concatenated, like this: "2016-11-23T23:59:59".

Instead, it just has the value of "23:59:59".

[image]

It looks like this has something to do with code formatting and splitting into multiple lines.

Of course I could use the full if/else notation, but why doesn't this notation work?

Comment: `+` has a higher precedence than `?`. You are not doing what you think you are. Your code is effectively `(value + (to_from === "to")) ? "T23:59:59" : "T00:00:00"`

Comment: Does your `value` variable has data?

Comment: Try with (value + ( (to_from === "to") ? "T23:59:59" : "T00:00:00"))  and be sure that `value` is not empty

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why is not working, but you can use join() for implode your data in a string

```
collectedValues = [];
key = "Created", 
value = "2016-11-23", 
to_from = "from"
collectedValues.push({
                key: key,
                value: [value, 
                    (to_from === "to") ?
                        "T23:59:59" :   
                        "T00:00:00"].join(""),   
                isPartialMatch: false,
                toFrom: to_from
            });
```